# SwiftUI DataStructure for ForEach.. (how to delete)

Tags: swiftui, foreach

I'm working on an app which show images when tapping buttons.

I have a 4 buttons, and Each buttons has a action that add a image.

The problem I have is that when I remove by ontapGesture, The deleting order is not my want.

Ex) button 1 -> button 2 -> button 3 -> button 4 : Now I can see 4 images in vstack, plus, minus, multiply, divide.

But If I tap button 1 now, the plus image still there.

I think the problem arises because of array. What dataStructure should I use instead?

`

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var array: [Int] = []
    
    let systemDictionary: [Int : Image] = [
        0 : Image(systemName: "plus.circle"),
        1 : Image(systemName: "minus.circle"),
        2 : Image(systemName: "multiply.circle"),
        3 : Image(systemName: "divide.circle")
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button {
                    array.append(0)
                } label: {
                    Text("Button 0")
                }
                Button {
                    array.append(1)
                } label: {
                    Text("Button 1")
                }
                Button {
                    array.append(2)
                } label: {
                    Text("Button 2")
                }
                Button {
                    array.append(3)
                } label: {
                    Text("Button 3")
                }

            }
            ForEach(array.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                systemDictionary[index]
                    .font(.system(size: 30))
                    .padding()
                    .onTapGesture {
                        array.remove(at: index)

                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`

I found out when I tap button 1 again, it delete the data in array[0].
But there is still array[0], because array always has index.

I understand! but I can not come up with data structure for images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your current setup, you could try this approach, using the content of the array `array[index]` for the index into `systemDictionary`, and to limit the set of images to 4 only, use `if !array.contains(0) { array.append(0) }` as shown in the code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var array: [Int] = []
    
    let systemDictionary: [Int : Image] = [
        0 : Image(systemName: "plus.circle"),
        1 : Image(systemName: "minus.circle"),
        2 : Image(systemName: "multiply.circle"),
        3 : Image(systemName: "divide.circle")
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button {
                    if !array.contains(0) { array.append(0) }  // <-- here
                } label: {
                    Text("Button 0")
                }
                Button {
                    if !array.contains(1) { array.append(1) }
                } label: {
                    Text("Button 1")
                }
                Button {
                    if !array.contains(2) { array.append(2) }
                } label: {
                    Text("Button 2")
                }
                Button {
                    if !array.contains(3) { array.append(3) }
                } label: {
                    Text("Button 3")
                }
            }
            
            ForEach(array.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                systemDictionary[array[index]] // <-- here
                    .font(.system(size: 30))
                    .padding()
                    .onTapGesture {
                        array.remove(at: index)
                    }
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT-1: using a specific structure for the images:

```
struct Picture: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var image: Image
    var label: String
    var isVisible: Bool = false
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var pictures: [Picture] = [
        Picture(image: Image(systemName: "plus.circle"), label: "Button 0"),
        Picture(image: Image(systemName: "minus.circle"), label: "Button 1"),
        Picture(image: Image(systemName: "multiply.circle"), label: "Button 2"),
        Picture(image: Image(systemName: "divide.circle"), label: "Button 3")
    ]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                ForEach($pictures) { $picture in
                    Button {
                        picture.isVisible = true
                    } label: {
                        Text(picture.label)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            ForEach($pictures) { $picture in
                if picture.isVisible {
                    picture.image
                        .font(.system(size: 30))
                        .padding()
                        .onTapGesture {
                            picture.isVisible = false
                        }
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try yours and let you know the result :)